# How to replace the "Go‎ ‎to‎‎ ToC" with an image in this file?

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

In the following code, how can I replace the "Go‎ ‎to‎‎ ToC" with [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHLrT.png) in the output pdf?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top]{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\usepackage{blindtext}
‎\SetBgContents{\hyperlink{toc}{Go‎ ‎to‎‎ ToC}}
\SetBgAngle{0}
\SetBgColor{black!40}
\SetBgScale{1}
\SetBgHshift{50}
\SetBgVshift{-9}
\begin{document}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\hypertarget{toc}{}}
\tableofcontents\newpage
\section{sec one}
\blindtext
\newpage
\section{sec two}
\blindtext
‎\end{document}‎
```

**Edit:**
Please note that the image should be created with something like tiKz. Because I want to send the output pdf to someone else.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saved the image down into the folder then modified as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top]{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\SetBgAngle{0}
\SetBgColor{black!40}
\SetBgScale{1}
\SetBgHshift{50}
\SetBgVshift{-9}

\begin{document}
‎\SetBgContents{\hyperlink{toc}{\includegraphics[scale=1]{image.png}}}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\hypertarget{toc}{}}
\tableofcontents\newpage
\section{sec one}
\blindtext
\newpage
\section{sec two}
\blindtext
‎\end{document}‎
```

Result Below: Note Box around Image, which comes from the hyperlink.

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks ADP, but I want to send the output pdf to someone else. Isn't there a way to create the image using something like Tikz?

Comment: I dont get it, once you have compiled it, the image is in the pdf, you can send it to anyone you want...

Comment: Ok, you are right, but the link to the ToC, does not work! How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It works for me, I compile using TexMaker IDE and PDFLaTeX. See the updated post, above.

Comment: but with Xelatex, it does not work!

Comment: You are right, just tried it, I don't know how to fix.

Comment: I don't know what is wrong with your `xelatex` compilations, but this works fine with mine. `Version 3.1415926-2.4-0.9998 (TeX Live 2012)`

Comment: I never use it, so it doesn't really bother me.

Comment: @hpesoj626 My version is exactly the same as yours, too! Isn't there another reason that causes the problem?

Comment: @Sisabe See [README](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/README.pdf) of package `hyperref` about `\XeTeXLinkBox`. It is a workaround for the deficiency of XeTeX to ignore stuff like images or rules in links that are not font glyphs.